# Debugging Informix 12.10 Stored Procedures

Tags: debugging, stored-procedures, informix

For the most part, most of the Informix versions I use are version 12.10.  When debugging a program in an IDE,  I can place a breakpoint point to stop program execution, and when the the breakpoint is reached, I can examine the call stack to determine the order which the methods were called.  Is there anything similar to the call stack to examine in Informix.

I am dealing with large legacy databases on several sites.  I need to determine the call order and execution of stored procedures to locate a logical error.  I don't really need the break point functionality.  I need the ability to find out what performed an insert into a particular table or called a stored procedure.  Was the insert or stored procedure called from another stored procedure or JDBC?